# Order by with underscores as highest sorting priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pulling large amounts of data from the DB and in order to not having to reassign it to the specific variables, I want to sort both alphabetically. Problem is, that the target variables are sorted with underscores coming first and then other letters. SQL returns the exact opposite.

Example:

*target:*

- A_Vers
- Adj_DT
- Adj_DT_Trans

*current return:*

- Adj_DT
- Adj_DT_Trans
- A_Vers

I've found solutions to getting defined conditions to the top of the ladder, but I really have no clue on how to solve this.

Comment: Do you have large amount of distinct values?

Comment: Do you want to sort only by the prefix (being defined as what comes before the first underscore), followed by the suffix?  How many underscores can possibly appear?  Your sample data already shows two, but could there be more than this?

Comment: @rohit yes, all the values that are to be sorted are distinct.

Comment: @Tim It's not supposed to go by prefix no, and there could be a much higher number of underscores, e.g. this: HLTH_RV_UEB_S2_rr_BE_Rvfin_all       It's also possible that there are blanks instead of underscores

Comment: @CrystalRain See Kevin's answer below, but maybe you should show us a more complete set of sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you probably want to use the REPLACE() function, and swap out those _'s for a character that's sorted before letters.

However, there's a bit of a complication: how large is your data, and how integral is the sorting to your code?  The reason I'm asking is because doing this sort of thing kinda makes any indexes on that column useless (because the index's ordering isn't what you're wanting.)

Take a look at 'Generated Columns' (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) - you may need to add a 'generated' column to your table, and then create an index on it.

Comment: Interference with the code was a problem, but I completely forgot generated columns. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem!  :-)  I just wanted to help avoid the situation where, down the line, you were wondering, "Why doesn't my search for A_Avg_Mkt find the data quickly?  I've got an index on that column - why is it doing a full scan instead of a seek?"

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
order by replace(col, '_', ' ')
```

Space comes before all letters, so this seems to do what you want.